# MS SQL - find out if a field exists within another

Tags: sql, string, select, substring, record

I have a table that, among its columns, has two particular char columns: "Code" and "Obs".

For example:

| Column1 | Code | Obs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 123 | This customer's code is 123 |

How do I find this record, based on the fact that the info on column "Code" is present in the info on column "Obs"?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [`charindex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  CHARINDEX(code, obs) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason this is happening?

```
SELECT num1, num2, CHARINDEX(num1, num2) as charindex
FROM   mytable
```

| Num1 | Num2 | charindex |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3456 | 123-456 | 0 |
| 3579 | 135790 | 0 |
| 35 | 35 | 1 |
| 35 | 351 | 0 |